# How to Achieve Pagination For Primefaces Sheet Table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions, primefaces-datatable

I would like to use pagination for Primefaces Sheet Table like how normal Primefaces Datatable does. I checked sheet properties to achive any pagination but it has no property to achieve this goal. @Melloware do you have any working about this or know how to achieve that ?

JSF: 2.2.1, PrimeFaces: 12.0.0, PrimeFaces Extensions: 12.0.5

Answer (score 1):

HandsonTable does not officially support pagination so its not supported by the PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet

See: https://forum.handsontable.com/t/column-sorting-with-pagination/6267